Remove the background of the bottom navigation
I am testing my React Native app on two devices. And for the past two days I've been trying to find a way to remove the background of the bottom navigation.
I've tried transparent mode, but it's not what I want because stuff such as snackbar go behind it. I don't want the background to be seen at all.
How can I accomplish this?
Device running Android 14.0

Device running Android 11.0


Are you using Compose or the view system in your app?

I guess you should use a SafeAreaView and then change its background.

Modify a theme to set Navigation bar to transparent. Something like this:
<style name="Theme.MyApp">
  <item name="android:navigationBarColor">
    @android:color/transparent
  </item>
</style>

See Set a navigation style for details.
